# PWM using bcm2835 library as non-root in Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ros, pwm

I need to control some DC motors using PWM. I have been trying to use the [bcm2835 library](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/), but I need root access to run my program. I need to avoid this, as this program is part of a ROS package, which gives problems if run as root. I have tried to follow the instructions that appear in the section "Running as root", but I haven't been successful. I have done the following.

First, I have installed libcap2 and libcap-dev and added my user to the kmem group.

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2 libcap-dev
sudo adduser ubuntu kmem
```

Then, I have installed the version latest version of bcm2835 library.

```
wget http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.67.tar.gz
tar zxvf bcm2835-1.67.tar.gz
cd bcm2835-1.67
./configure
make
sudo make check
sudo make install
```

After that, I uncommented the `#define BCM2835_HAVE_LIBCAP` line in `bcm2835.h`, which I found in `/usr/local/include/`.

I allowed write access to /dev/mem by members of kmem group.

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="mem", KERNEL=="mem", GROUP="kmem", MODE="0660"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/98-mem.rules
sudo reboot
```

And finally, I compiled my program (called `l298n`) and run the following command.

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio+ep l298n
```

After doing all this, my program is still not able to provide PWM control unless I run it as root.

Have I done anything wrong? Is there any other way around this? As far as I know, other libraries would run into the same problem, as it depends on the access level of `/dev/mem`.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong:

1. You edited the wrong bcm2835.h, you need to edit bcm2835.h where ever you unpacked bcm2835-1.67.tar.gz, not /usr/local/include.
2. You didn't recompile the library to actually have the added feature in it.

Also, if you're just accessing the GPIO pins and don't need non-root access to /dev/mem then there's no need to do anything more than adding access rights to /dev/gpiomem to your non-root user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried version 68 already ?

There where made some changings concerning 'BCM2835_HAVE_LIBCAP'.